# PHP Не получается найти расхождение массивов. Примеры обоих внутри

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два массива:

Первый:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mrt_id] => 2
            [mr_agent] => 1
            [mr_contragent] => 4
            [mr_status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mrt_id] => 3
            [mr_agent] => 1
            [mr_contragent] => 4
            [mr_status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mrt_id] => 2
            [mr_agent] => 4
            [mr_contragent] => 6
            [mr_status] => 1
        )
)
```

Второй:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [mrt_id] => 2
        [mr_agent] => 2
        [mr_contragent] => 4
        [mr_status] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [mrt_id] => 2
            [mr_agent] => 1
            [mr_contragent] => 4
            [mr_status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mrt_id] => 3
            [mr_agent] => 1
            [mr_contragent] => 4
            [mr_status] => 1
        )
)
```

Использую методы:

```
$result = array_diff(первый, второй);
$result = array_diff_assoc(первый, второй);
```

Но выдает ошибку:

```
Array to string conversion
```

Что не так?
может быть еще есть какие то нюансы?
**Как найти расхождения?**

Answer (score 2):

[Смотрим в книгу](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php) относительно используемых вами функций:

> Замечание:      Два элемента считаются одинаковыми тогда и только тогда, если `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`. Другими словами, когда их строковое представление идентично.

Отсюда возникают  ваши сообщения об ошибках, и как следствие сравнение не работает.

Поскольку сравниваете вы, очевидно, не строки а вложенные массивы, то используйте пользовательскую функцию сравнения совместно с [`array_udiff`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php):

```
$result = array_udiff($first, $second, function($a,$b){
                   return $a != $b;
              });
```

Оператор [сравнения массивов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.array.php)  `!=` проверяет соответствие ключей и их значений.

---

В дополнение к комментариям в под ответом,  `diff`-функции возвращают элементы первого массива, которые не содержаться в остальных массивах. Если же нужно возвратить элементы из обоих массивов, то можно объединить результаты вызовов `udiff($first, $second)` и `udiff($second, $first)`. Однако все же придется написать  нормальную функцию сравнения, которая по правилам вернет 1/0/-1. В моем примере возвращается 0/1, что не совсем корректно.

Ваше замечание по поводу сравнения ключей не совсем уместно. Я в ответе про ключи писал относительно вложенных массивов, там у нас ключи везде совпадают. Сама udiff ключи не сравнивает.

Вам нужно написать корректную функцию сравнения, вида

```
$map = function($a, $b) {
            if ($a == $b) return 0;

            if(...) return 1
            else return -1;
        }

$r1 = array_udiff($first, $second, $map);
$r2 = array_udiff($second, $first, $map);
$result = array_merge($r1, $r2);
```

Другой вариант решения задачи - неким образом преобразовать элементы массива, чтобы получить из него хэш. Слить оба массива и подсчитать число повторов хэшей. Уникальными будут элементы где хэш повторяется только 1 раз.

Если тривиально взять за функцию хэширования сериализацию в json, то например так

```
$res = array_map('json_encode', array_merge($first, $second) );
$res = array_count_values($res);
$res = array_filter($res, function($v){ return $v == 1; });
$res = array_map('json_decode', array_keys($res));
```

Comment: но ведь ключи могут не совпадать, в этом случае он найдет расхождения верно? дополнил вопрос (добавил еще один элемент во второй массив). То есть если функция работает верно то на выходе у меня должен быть два элемента один уникальный с первого, другой - со второго.

Comment: да проверил если ключи не совпадают то функция считает элемент массива уникальным, кажется придется элементы обоих массивов к строке, искать расхождения а потом снова парсить

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов `diff`-функции возвращают элементы первого массива, а не уникальные

Comment: фактически вам надо получается слить массивы, и посчитать число вхождений элементов, отобрав те, где количество равно 1, а не "расхождение"

Comment: не совсем понял, ну вот из моего примера в вопросе, на выходе должно остаться два элемента. Но если воспользоваться вашей функцией то в  $result попадут все 6 элементов так как ключи нигде не спадают. А мне как раз и нужно получить массив с уникальными элементами чтобы добавить его в базу. Другие элементы не попавшие в массив соответственно уже есть в базе

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов несколько дополнил ответ